# Transforming a private research project repository into an open-source repository

Tags: code, open-science, repository

Our research project is ready for being shared as a preprint and submitted for peer review. What are the best practices for transforming the private research repository (which includes several pilot experiments and paths not taken) into a codebase that can be shared as supporting material?

In principle, we can create a new repository with a single cleaned-up version. The downside of this would be a split between the actual research repository and the published one, and the omission of the commit history, which provides specific credit to the different students who contributed to different parts of the code. (to make this clear, these students are also listed as authors.)

EDIT: This question originally mentioned GitHub. I edited it to remove the mention of this service. As some of the comments suggested, there are alternative platforms that can be used for the task. This is a general question on how one should transform a private codebase into something that can be shared as an open scientific code.

Comment: have a look at Zenodo.org , instead of being dependent on commercial endeavours that in theory may disappear tomorrow after a market crash.

Comment: Might be a better question for support at github (or dedicated forums).  This issue won't be unique to academia.

Comment: I am not convinced that commit history is a useful way to give credit.

Comment: @Ian I am not underestimating GitHub, if you scratch the fancy layout of that site, they are simply associating with some other institutions to provide storage, institutions that are more stable than a for-profit company.  
In fact, one of the best way to preserve your GitHub is to do so through zenodo.org , but I do not see it as "look how nice they are the GitHub guys, they allow to preserve your repository somewhere else for free", rather I see it as "people at GitHub know that they may fold down any moment, so they found a way for free to provide safety to their content provider".

Comment: "Do we worry that our Excel spreadsheets will stop working?" yes, in fact while the average Joe employed in a financial company does "finance" with Excel, COBOL is used for critical applications ( http://fingfx.thomsonreuters.com/gfx/rngs/USA-BANKS-COBOL/010040KH18J/ ).
A part from being a theoretical risk, there is the exploitation factor: if a for-profit company is providing you something for free, you are the product. Isn't the peer reviewing provided to for-profit editors enough as a gift from academics to companies?

Comment: @EarlGrey Haha, that's a fair point. I'm going to clean up my comments. Cheers.

Comment: @EarlGrey Zenodo looks interesting, tho I have to admit I've heard the word before but never knew what it refers to. It seems like you can link your GitHub uploads to a Zenodo item, which is neat. However, unless Zenodo directly supports Git (not the Company GitHub, but Git: free and open source distributed version control system) it is really not suitable for a collaborative maintenance of software projects.

Comment: @EarlGrey Additionally, and more importantly, while you make good points about data storage and GitHub, to the best of my knowledge, distributing your code through GitHub is a _defacto standard_ in Computer Science, and certainly Computer Vision. All CV papers from the last few years which have shared their code have done so through GitHub repositories, and everything else would certainly stand out.

Comment: @penelope you are mixing up things. Zenodo is (at minimum) the tool to have a permanent storage space for a DOI indexed code. Code that is **permanent**. Once the record has been published, you can no longer change the files in the record. How you prepared that code, on github-gitlab or using git-svn or your own custom version control it is not relevant.
If GitHub is a *defacto standard* in your field, I unfortunately can only point at the fact that in the cotton farming industry slavery was the *defacto standard*. Surely, standing out may bring some question, which also bring **visibility**.

Comment: @EarlGrey I wasn't arguing about whether the standard was good on bad, or that it shouldn't be challenged. Just that it is, in fact, a standard in a well-established academic field, which in my opinion makes this question on-topic (not just as a response to you but also a number of close votes). Sorry for the mix-up. And possibly putting it in the same context to slavery is pushing it a bit. Peer reviewed publications, and comparing academic profiles in terms of citations both standard practices with a number of downsides, but both on-topic on the site (with their downsides discussed often).

Comment: @penelope I am not arguing about the topic being on-question (in fact I commented it), but I wanted to make it clear the distinction between github and zenodo. The defacto comparison is unfortunately extreme, and it is the only way to show how the defacto standards are seldom neutral, rarely efficent. I comment similarly when people asks about "*notorius-for-profit-ad-placement-company* scholar": making any aspect of research dependable on some for-profit private tool (ditto for publishing, ditto for open-source hosted in GitHub ... Copilot® says thanks to all for your free work) is terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the best practices for transforming the private research GitHub repository (which includes several pilot experiments and paths not taken) into a codebase that can be shared as supporting material?

For best practices, first determine where you want to host your code. You have two options, each with tradeoffs. Here are the two I could consider:

1. Make your GitHub repo public and create an immutable tag with the version.

   - Downsides: You depend upon GitHub being public *forever*, Some countries block GitHub, GitHub might fall out of favor with researchers.
   - Upsides: GitHub is the lingua franca for open science right now, having your code public would increase it's visibility, your complete workflow is open source.
2. Put a snapshot of the code somewhere else either as a supplement with the journal or on a long term digital archive such as Zenodo.org (thanks to EarlGrey for suggesting in a comment).

   - Downsides: Need to make sure you archived version matches final version, less visible, slightly more work.
   - Upside: Should be around for a really long time, you get a DOI minted for your code.

Personally, I would combine options 1 and 2. Specifically, if I wanted the code to be public, I would clean up the repo and then make it public. I would create a tag for the final version of code used for the paper and then put an archive on Zenodo.org. I recently did this for a paper I had published in the [Journal of Open Source Softwware](https://joss.theoj.org/)

Second, make sure your repository is clean.
My agency has guidance for scientists who develop code, some of which would be helpful for you.
The full page is [here](https://www.usgs.gov/products/software/software-management).
I would also look for domain specific best practices.
For example, the article, [Ten Simple Rules for Taking Advantage of Git and GitHub](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004947), has been published in PLOS Computational Biology.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience working in a simulation-oriented computational science, I'd recommend *simply setting the repository to visibility to public*.

**The crucial steps in making this work are:**

1. Making sure that *documentation* accompanies the repository on a per-publication basis
2. Making sure that the *state of the codebase* used to produce each publication is captured alongside the analytical code and documentation. **This includes package versions.**
3. Adding a license

Organizationally -- particularly for projects with multiple papers -- splitting the repository into separate archival branches has been critical. Paper 1 gets a branch, with a readme explaining the layout of the project and the specifics needed to replicate the results. Links to the paper itself and other supporting documentation also belong there along with the versions of the software packages used. Leaving out the packages can destroy replicability.

Paper 2, …, Paper n get the same treatment.

We keep working branches in active development for further work when relevant.

**Judging your success:**

If you can take a paper, strip out all the tables and figures, and reconstruct it using only that paper’s github branch then you have a foothold (streamlining this can yield great improvements in your analytical workflow for the next project).

You'll know that you hit actual reproducibility when you can send a link to someone who was not on the project and they can do the same.

Comment: All good points. Aren't you concerned about including the entire development history of the project in the repository? files that are no longer relevant? analyses not described in the papers?

Comment: You can cull or organize files in the archival branches if they are a particularly onerous issue, but as long as the documentation is very clear it should be obvious which parts are actually used in replicating the paper. If they are not mentioned in a procedure, they can simply be ignored by the reader.


IMO these presentation concerns are secondary to simply having code publicly available and in a usable state. Papers and docs are the parts that give the code clarity. 


Tidying code is vital, but I would urge you to build that into your workflow rather than as a publication step.